# Automation studio schedule

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

If I have several scheduled automations is it recommended to start them all at the same time or is it better to schedule them?

Comment: If all your automations are independent of each other then you can start at the same time. It's good to give a clear background on your question.

Comment: If you do not start them at the full hour / half hour mark, but at off times, you can expect them to start a few minutes faster than if they hit the stack-wide peak times. The effect of automations within your system on each other is likely negligible.